# Finding left and right heigth in Binary Search Tree

Tags: typescript, binary-search-tree

How can I find the length of the path from the root to the deepest node in the tree for two side? I mean I can find the **max height** of the tree with `height()` method as below code. I can find max height with that code line`1 + Math.max(this._height(root.getleft()), this._height(root.getright()))`. There is any way to find height of **left** side and height of **right** side.
Thanks,

```
const inputString1 = `13
    25
    39
    12
    19
    9
    23
    55
    31
    60
    35
    41
    70
    90`;
    //left 3 right 5
    const inputLines1: string[] = inputString1.split("\n");
    let leftHeight = 0;
    let rightHeight = 0;
    let currentLine1: number = 0;
    function readLine1(): string {
      return inputLines1[currentLine1++];
    }
    
    class TreeNode1<T> {
      private _value: T;
      public getvalue(): T {
        return this._value;
      }
      public setvalue(v: T) {
        this._value = v;
      }
    
      private _left: TreeNode1<T>;
    
      public getleft(): TreeNode1<T> {
        return this._left;
      }
    
      public setleft(node: TreeNode1<T>) {
        this._left = node;
      }
    
      private _right: TreeNode1<T>;
    
      public getright(): TreeNode1<T> {
        return this._right;
      }
    
      public setright(node: TreeNode1<T>) {
        this._right = node;
      }
    
      constructor(value: T) {
        this._value = value;
        this._left = null as any;
        this._right = null as any;
      }
    }
    
    class BinarySearchTree1<T> {
      leftHeight:number=0;
      rightHeight:number=0;
      height() {
        return this._height(this._root);
      }
    
      _height(root?: TreeNode1<T>): any {
        if (!root || (root.getleft() == null && root.getright() == null)) {
          return 0;
        }
    
        return (
          1 + Math.max(this._height(root.getleft()), this._height(root.getright()))
        );
      }
    
      private _root: TreeNode1<T>;
      public getroot(): TreeNode1<T> {
        return this._root;
      }
    
      public setroot(v: TreeNode1<T>) {
        this._root = v;
      }
      constructor() {
        this._root = null as any;
      }
    
      addToTree(v: T): boolean | undefined {
        const newNode = new TreeNode1(v);
        if (this._root == null) {
          this._root = newNode;
          return true;
        } else {
          let currentNode = this.getroot();
          let traversing = true;
          while (traversing) {
            if (currentNode != null) {
              if (currentNode.getvalue() == newNode.getvalue()) {
                traversing = false;
                return false;
              } else if (currentNode.getvalue() > newNode.getvalue()) {
                if (currentNode.getleft() == null) {
                  currentNode.setleft(newNode);
                  traversing = false;
                  return true;
                } else {
                  currentNode = currentNode.getleft();
                }
              } else {
                if (currentNode.getright() == null) {
                  currentNode.setright(newNode);
                  traversing = false;
                  return true;
                } else {
                  currentNode = currentNode.getright();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    
      BFS(): T[] {
        let queue = new Array<TreeNode1<T>>();
        let visited = new Array<T>();
        queue.push(this._root);
        while (queue.length != 0) {
          let currentNode = queue.shift();
          if (currentNode !== null) {
            visited.push(currentNode!!.getvalue());
          }
    
          if (currentNode !== null) {
            if (currentNode!!.getleft() !== null)
              queue.push(currentNode!!.getleft());
            if (currentNode!!.getright !== null)
              queue.push(currentNode!!.getright());
          }
        }
        return visited;
      }
    }
    
    function main1() {
      let myBST = new BinarySearchTree1<number>();
      for (let i = 1; i < inputLines1.length; i++) {
        myBST.addToTree(Number(inputLines1[i]));
      }
      console.log("BFS: " + myBST.BFS(), myBST.height());
      console.log(leftHeight, rightHeight);
    }
    
    main1();
```

Comment: You're already using the left and right heights to calculate the full height.   Like,  `this._height(root.getleft())` gives you the height of the left side of the tree.   Does that make sense?

Comment: I can find those heights if call them with different functions like that ``leftHeight() {
    return this._leftH(this._root) + 1;
  }
  _leftH(root?: TreeNode1<T>): any {
    if (!root || (root.getleft() == null)) {
      return 0;
    } if (root.getleft()) {
      leftHeight++;
      return this._height(root.getleft());
    }
  }``  But I want to find those heights in one method which here ``height()``method. :) I think I am not good for recursion...

Comment: You just need `get leftHeight() { return this._height(this._root.getleft()) }; get rightHeight() { return this._height(this._root.getright()) };`, right?  Did you not write this code to begin with?

Comment: Where should I add this code?  Can you give me a bunch of line codes with that your solution at least I can understand where should I put it? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the height of a tree that has no nodes, is -1, as can be read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29#Terminology):

> Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are allowed) has height −1.

So your `height` method should be corrected to:

```
  _height(root?: TreeNode1<T>): number {
    if (!root) {
      return -1;
    }
    return (
      1 + Math.max(this._height(root.getleft()), this._height(root.getright()))
    );
  }
```

Then, remove the `leftHeight` and `rightHeight` members, and instead make them *methods*:

```
  leftHeight(): number {
    if (!this._root) {
      return -2;
    }
    return this._height(this._root.getleft());
  }
  rightHeight(): number {
    if (!this._root) {
      return -2;
    }
    return this._height(this._root.getright());
  }
```

...and call them in your main function.

Comment: Firstly. thanks for your answer , when I was re-edited that line ``return this._height(this._root.getleft());`` to ``1+    return this._height(this._root.getleft());`` it worked. But , my concern is that how  can I get right and left heights in ``_height`` method  instead of using different methods ? I want to create global properies like ``let leftHeight:number;  let rightHeight:number;`` and call them wherever I want instead of calling with method. I know it looks weird but it is challenge for me :) so I wanted find it...

Comment: I would not add 1 to what `this._height` returns, as it will count the height from the root, not the subtree. It that is what you wanted, OK, but the definition of the height of a subtree is that you only look at that subtree, and count from the root of the subtree. So you should not add 1 then. I don't understand what the issue is with having a method. If you want to store the result of a call in another property, you can of course do so, and then only read that property when you need it again. I suppose you know how to do that, as it is basic compared to the code you already wrote.

Comment: One more thing: if you wanted the `height` function to *store* the height of left and right subtree, then that is a bad design: a function should *either* return a result, *or* modify the state (like setting properties), but *not both*. That is bad practice. If you want to set properties, then create one function that doesn't return anything, and which does the job. It can call the functions I provided, and store the result in other properties.